# How to test for leading hyphen in bash script conditional using regex

Tags: regex, bash

This code does not seem to stop when there are no more hyphens ... what am I doing wrong?

```
hortense$ if [[ $BFILE =~ ^[-]* ]] ; then BFILE=${BFILE:1} ; fi

hortense$ echo $BFILE

Atbari

hortense$ if [[ $BFILE =~ ^[-]* ]] ; then BFILE=${BFILE:1} ; fi

hortense$ echo $BFILE

tbari
```

Comment: `Atbari` starts with 0 or more `-` characters.

Comment: More idiomatic: `if [[ $bfile = -* ]]; then bfile=${bfile#?}; fi`: You don't need regexes, you don't need substring parameter expansion to remove just the first character, and you want to use lower case variable names. Sadly, many people here will not show you good practices... they'll only give you the quick and dirty answer just to get reputation.

Comment: This question in answered!  Thank you both.  I will work on learning the significance of uppercase variable names.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `^[-]*` means *starts with 0 or more `-`*.
So it matches even if there are no `-` at all.

Change the `*` to `+` to require at least one `-`.

Also, instead of `[-]` you can write simply `-`.

Putting it all together:

```
if [[ $BFILE =~ ^-+ ]] ; then BFILE=${BFILE:1} ; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could skip regex altogether:

```
if [[ ${BFILE:0:1} == - ]] ...
```